# Can we create a google glass app without using Card?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

Me and my friends are trying to work with Google Glass.  We need to know whether the google glass app can be created without a card.

Comment: What do you want your app to do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You can use the Glass Development Kit (GDK), an add-on to the Android SDK. See https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/.

The GDK is harder to use than the Mirror API, since you'd be writing an Android app, but it is also much more powerful than the Mirror API.

Comment: Specifically, you'll probably want to use the immersion user interface pattern since it is using "plain old" android activities. Just note that glass only supports certain kinds of layouts. All of which is pretty well documented in the link included in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create a software to run on any of the OS if they're having an API. Because API is required to understand how the OS would perform a task.

You can try out https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ from the Google's Developer Network. They would train you in a better way.

And I am not able to understand the `card` part where you're trying to imply that you want to create the app without a card.

To create an app that would have more control over the Glass's hardware you can create the App using the GlassAPI (GDK). It is more like a low-level app.

On the main page, you can find out that the Glass would also use the **.apk** files that are used to install the application softwares on Android OS. So, coding in Android SDK and then installing the very same app on the Google Glass would also be a good idea.